# String.raw with a string only works without parenthesis

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I know you can use template literals to supply the first parameter of a method, for instance:

```
const f = x => "hello ," + x;
f`world` // returns 'hello, world'
```

So I can somehow understand why this code works:

```
String.raw`bla bla`
```

However, I can't seem to understand why the same method call with parenthesis throws an error:

```
String.raw(`bla bla`)
```

throws: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

My questions are:

- Why exactly the first snippet works? why can I replace parenthesis with template literals in a method call?
- Why `String.raw` only works when it's being called this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ... I can't seem to understand why the same method call with parenthesis throws an error

It's not the same method call.

This:

```
String.raw`bla blah`
```

...calls `raw` passing in the *template*.

But this:

```
String.raw(`bla blah`)
```

...processes the template, creating a string, and then calls `raw` with that string. Exactly as though you'd written:

```
const str = `bla blah`;
String.raw(str);
```

...but without the constant.

That's not the same thing at all.

> Why exactly the first snippet works?

Because that's how *tagged template literals* work. They're their own thing.

> Why `String.raw` only works when it's being called this way?

Because it's designed to be run as a tag function, but you're calling it like a non-tag function and not passing it the information a tag function receives when called as a tag function.

It might help if you see what a tag function receives:

```js
function foo(strings, ...tokenValues) {
    console.log("strings: ", JSON.stringify(strings));
    console.log("strings.raw: ", JSON.stringify(strings.raw));
    console.log("Token values (" + tokenValues.length + "):");
    tokenValues.forEach((val, index) => {
      console.log(`${index}: ${typeof val}: ${JSON.stringify(val)}`);
    });
}
const token = "tokenValue";
const obj = {
   foo: "bar",
   num: Math.random()
};
foo`bla \nbla ${token} bla ${obj} done`;
```

Note how the function receives an array with the non-token parts of the template (the "strings"), followed by arguments with the values of each token. Also note that those values are the **actual** values, not strings of the values.

More about template literals and tag functions:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [Exploring ES6: Template literals](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_template-literals.html)

Comment: Also, here's a decent article that helped me understand: https://codeburst.io/javascript-template-literals-tag-functions-for-beginners-758a041160e1

Comment: Might I suggest adding logging the "invisible" `raw` property of the first argument to the tag function in the example, which `String.raw` actually uses to do its magic?

Comment: @Nickolay: **Very** good point. Done! And I threw in an escape sequence so people could see the difference with `strings`.

Comment: Here are some common use cases for tag functions (for people who reads this question in the future): https://github.com/declandewet/common-tags

Comment: Same :) it was a very helpful and quick answer @T.J.Crowder, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Or if you want to call String.raw as a function you need to call it like this

```
String.raw({raw: `xyx`})
```

As mentioned in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw documentation

Two ways of calling String.raw

```
String.raw(callSite, ...substitutions)

String.raw`templateString`
```