# How Can I Call a Template Literal Tag Function on a Regular String?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals

If I have a template literal tag function `foo`, which let's me do:

```
const fooTaggedText = foo`some text`;
```

is it possible for me to somehow call that tag on a regular string?  For instance:

```
 // This doesn't actually work
 const fooTaggedText = foo('some text');
```

Comment: Yes, of course you can, but if you look at your definition of `foo` the parameter type doesn't fit.

Comment: So, to put it another way, my question is: how do I "make it fit"?

Comment: A tag function expects an array as its first argument - surely you know this if you've implemented it? So just `foo(['some text'])` will most likely work, unless the tag function is using some of the more intricate features.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [String.raw with a string only works without parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48303046/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got it, but wouldn't this work?

```
const taggedText = str => foo`${str}`;
```

So you'd use it like:

```
taggedText('my string')

// foo`my string`
```

Please give some rep if it helps :)

Comment: Could those available to give bad reputation at least provide some explanation of why is it a bad answer?

Comment: Actually this seems like a great answer to me, only ... the tag I'm trying to do this to doesn't allow string interpolation :(  (It's the `graphql` tag from Gatsby, if anyone cares.)  But since I didn't mention that in my question, I'm going to accept this and ask a new one that explicitly prohibits string interpolation

Comment: P.S. If anyone cares *that* question is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63710229/how-can-i-call-a-template-literal-tag-function-on-a-regular-string-without-i

Comment: thanks! I use tag query on Gatsby as well so I'll certainly take a look