# How Can I Call a Template Literal Tag Function on a Regular String (*Without* Interpolating That String In)?

Tags: gatsby, template-literals

The `graphql` tag in Gatsby is ... finicky.    If you try to use string interpolation inside it:

```
import queryString from './queries/someQuery'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';

export const query = gql`${queryString}`;
```

You get:

> String interpolations are not allowed in graphql fragments. Included fragments should be referenced as `...MyModule_foo`.

My question is, is there any way to "call that tag function" (or really *any* template literal tag function) on an ordinary (`'hello world'`) string, instead of on a template literal string?  Something *like*:

```
export const query = gql(...magicTransformationFunction(queryString));
```

As a side note, I asked this question already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63697250/how-can-i-call-a-template-literal-tag-function-on-a-regular-string?noredirect=1#comment112637903_63697250), but left off the detail about not being able to do string interpolation, and so now I'm re-asking with that (very relevant) detail.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve with that. What does `queryString` contain?

Comment: Apparently [you cannot do this](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/page-query/#the-longer-answer) as gatsby does special magic instead of just calling the function as javascript.

Comment: You might want to try using fragments instead of attempting to import the whole query from another file?

Comment: I'm trying to re-use an entire query, so fragments won't help, but thanks for that link Bergi!